Accessing a sheet from a different workbook
I have 2 workbooks, one hidden and one the user can see.
The hidden workbook contains all the code (including the line below)
Note: codeName is the code name of a sheet in the active (non-hidden) workbook
ActiveWorkbook.codeName.Range(cell).Value should return the value from the non-hidden sheet, right?
Instead I get error 438 "object doesn't support this property or method"
What am I doing wrong?
